# How to get the specific attribute of a class instance using one of its attributes & how to get a name of a class instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript it is very possible that this code is utter garbage, please feel free to recommend a better way to organize this data rather than classes if its more functional.

> Consider this:

```
  class hkr {
  constructor(romaji, hiragana, katakana, index) {
    this.romaji = romaji;
    this.hiragana = hiragana;
    this.katakana = katakana;
    this.index = index;
  }
}

const a = new hkr('a', 'あ', "ア", 1);
```

> I want to access a specific instance of a class

```
hkr(unknown instance of a class).(index given)
```

I would like to get the name of that instance and get the hiragana part

i know that `console.log(a.hiragana)` would work but how can i get a name of an instance by inserting one of the attributes?

> Another thing that is hard for me to understand why only the last option works:

```
let test = input_romaji.value; 
console.log(test.index); 
console.log(input_romaji.value.index); 
console.log(wo.index);
```

> So my problem is that I used to have something like this:

```
const a=0, i=1, u=2, e=3, o=4, ka=5, ki=6, ku=7,
     ke=8, ko=9, sa=10, shi=11, su=12, se=13, so=14,
      ta=15, chi=16, tsu=17, te=18, to=19,na=20, ni=21,
       nu=22, ne=23, no=24, ha=25, hi=26,hu =27, he=28,
        ho=29, ma=30, mi=31, mu=32, me=33, mo=34, ya=35,
         yu=36, yo=37, ra=38, ri=39, ru=40, re=41, ro=42, 
          wa=43, wo=44, n = 45
    // constants
    hkr_dict={ 
            hiragana_full: 
            ["あ", "い", "う", "え", "お","か","き","く","け","こ","さ","し",
            "す","せ","そ","た","ち","つ","て","と","な","に","ぬ","ね","の","は","ひ","ふ",
            "へ","ほ","ま","み","む","め","も","や","ゆ","よ","ら","り","る","れ","ろ","わ",
            "を","ん"],
    
            katakana_full:
            ["ア","イ","ウ","エ","オ","カ","キ","ク","ケ","コ","サ","シ","ス",
            "セ","ソ","タ","チ","ツ","テ","ト","ナ","ニ","ヌ","ネ","ノ","ハ","ヒ","フ","ヘ","ホ",
            "マ","ミ","ム","メ","モ","ヤ","ユ","ヨ","ラ","リ","ル","レ","ロ","ワ","ヲ","ン"],
    
            romaji_full:
            ["a","i","u","e","o","ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","sa","shi","su",
            "se","so","ta","chi","tsu","te","to","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","hu"
            ,"he","ho","ma","mi","mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro",
            "wa","wo","n"],
```

> But now I have this:

```
    };
 <!-- HTML-->
    <article class = "regular" >
    <!-- label for textbox-->
        <label for="romaji">Enter the correct romaji.</label>
        <input type="text" id="romaji" maxlength="4">
    <!-- button here-->
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Click to submit">
    <p class="output" id="output1"></p>
    <p class="output" id="output2"></p>

</article>
<!-- Input textbox with eventListener to check if input is correct-->
    
<script>
// Javascript

// variables
let input_romaji = document.getElementById('romaji'); 
let btn1 = document.getElementById('button1'); 
let out1 = document.getElementById('output1'); 
let out2_romaji = document.getElementById('output2_romaji'); 
let rng_num = 0

class hkr {
  constructor(romaji, hiragana, katakana, index) {
    this.romaji = romaji;
    this.hiragana = hiragana;
    this.katakana = katakana;
    this.index = index;
  }
}

const a =   new hkr('a', 'あ', "ア", 1);
const i =   new hkr('i', 'い', "イ", 2);
const u =   new hkr('u', 'う', "ウ", 3);
const e =   new hkr('e', 'え', "エ", 4);
const o =   new hkr('o', 'お', "オ", 5);

const ka =  new hkr('ka', 'か', "カ", 6);
const ki =  new hkr('ki', 'き', "キ", 7);
const ku =  new hkr('ku', 'く', "ク", 8);
const ke =  new hkr('ke', 'け', "ケ", 9);
const ko =  new hkr('ko', 'こ', "コ", 10);

const sa =  new hkr('sa', 'さ', "サ",  11);
const shi = new hkr('shi', 'し', "シ", 12);
const su =  new hkr('su', 'す', "ス", 13);
const se =  new hkr('se', 'せ', "セ", 14);
const so =  new hkr('so', 'そ', "ソ", 15);

const ta =  new hkr('ta', 'た', "タ", 16);
const chi = new hkr('chi', 'ち', "チ", 17);
const tsu = new hkr('tsu', 'つ', "ツ", 18);
const te =  new hkr('te', 'て', "テ", 19);
const to =  new hkr('to', 'と', "ト", 20);

const na =  new hkr('na', 'な', "ナ", 21);
const ni =  new hkr('ni', 'に', "ニ", 22);
const nu =  new hkr('nu', 'ぬ', "ヌ", 23);
const ne =  new hkr('ne', 'ね', "ネ", 24);
const no =  new hkr('no', 'の', "ノ", 25);

const ha =  new hkr('ha', 'は', "ハ", 26);
const hi =  new hkr('hi', 'ひ', "ヒ", 27);
const hu =  new hkr('hu', 'ふ', "フ", 28);
const he =  new hkr('he', 'へ', "ヘ", 29);
const ho =  new hkr('ho', 'ほ', "ホ", 30);

const ma =  new hkr('ma', 'ま', "マ", 31);
const mi =  new hkr('mi', 'み', "ミ", 32);
const mu =  new hkr('mu', 'む', "ム", 33);
const me =  new hkr('me', 'め', "メ", 34);
const mo =  new hkr('mo', 'も', "モ", 35);

const ya =  new hkr('ya', 'や', "ヤ", 36);
const yu =  new hkr('yu', 'ゆ', "ユ", 37);
const yo =  new hkr('yo', 'よ', "ヨ", 38);

const ra =  new hkr('ra', 'ら', "ラ", 39);
const ri =  new hkr('ri', 'り', "リ", 40);
const ru =  new hkr('ru', 'る', "ル", 41);
const re =  new hkr('re', 'れ', "レ", 42);
const ro =  new hkr('ro', 'ろ', "ロ", 43);

const wa =  new hkr('wa', 'わ', "ワ", 44);
let wo =    new hkr('wo', 'を', "ヲ", 44);
const n =   new hkr('n', 'ん', "ン", 45);

console.log(a.romaji);
console.log(a.katakana); 
console.log(a.katakana); 
console.log(a.index); 
console.log(i.romaji);
console.log(i.hiragana); 
console.log(i.katakana); 
console.log(i.index); 

if (a.index != i.index){
    console.log("failure")
    console.log()
}

// functions
function rng_romaji(){
        rng_num = Math.floor(Math.random()* (47-0)) + 0;
        return rng_num

    }
    
function get_input(){
    out1.innerHTML = input_romaji.value;
    let test = input_romaji.value;
    console.log("test:", test);
    console.log(test.romaji);
    console.log(test.hiragana); 
    console.log(test.katakana); 
    console.log(test.index); 
    console.log(wo.index); 
    rng_romaji();
    console.log("rng",rng_romaji());
    console.log("so-15",so.index);
    console.log("typed",(input_romaji.value));
    if ((input_romaji.value == hkr[6]) ){
        out1.innerHTML =hkr.rng_num;
        console.log("success")


    }
}


// accessibility
btn1.addEventListener('click', get_input)
</script>
<script>
    // out1.innerHTML = hkr_dict.hiragana_full[rng_romaji()]
</script>
```

Comment: Use an array or an object. You can't get variable programmatically in any other way

Comment: @Konrad oh... then if it would be with objects how would I do that then?

Comment: Just creating those objects achieves nothing. You'll need to put them into a collection that you can search through, e.g. an array or a `Map`.

Comment: @Bergi can you make just one for reference so I know how to implement that then?

Comment: `const vocals = [undefined, a, i, u, e, o]; function getByIndex(i) { return vocals[i]; }`